# Math program using switch case statement

Tags: java

I'm currently typing up a simple program with methods and a switch case that uses a person's response to add, multiply, subtract or divide by calling the corresponding method depending upon the user's input.

I'm having three problems:

1. My switch statement isn't working
2. The program is asking me to initialize the variable `answer`, but when I set it to 0, I always get a response of 0, no matter what the equation is.
3. My method isn't returning the answer, but it will show the correct answer when I output from within the method. Here is my code below and my compiling error.

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Math {

    public static void main (String[] args){

        //used to import scanner class for keyboard use
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        //used to hold value of first number
        int a;
        //used to hold the value of the second number
        int b;
        //used to hold value for response of line 29
        int d;

        //out put message to user
        System.out.println("Please enter a whole number between 0 and 100.");
        a = kb.nextInt();

        if (a > 100) {
            System.out.println("The number you entered did not match the criteria, please run the program again.");
            System.exit(0);
        } else
            System.out.println("Please enter another whole number between 0 and 100.");

        b = kb.nextInt();

        if (b > 100) {
            System.out.println("The number you entered did not match the criteria, please run the program again.");
            System.exit(0);
        } else
            System.out.println("What would you like to do with these two numbers?");

        System.out.println("1=Add, 2=Subtraction, 3=Multiply, 4=Divide");

        d = kb.nextInt();

          switch(d){

          case '1':
              System.out.println("you choose addition!");
              add(a, b);
              break;

          case '2':
              subtract(a, b);
              break;

          case '3':
              multiply(a, b);
              break;

          case '4':
              divide(a, b);
              break;

          default:
              System.out.println("You did not make a valid choice, please run the program again.");
              System.exit(0);
          }
    }

    public static int add(int x, int y){
        int answer;
        answer = x+y;
        return answer;
    }

    public static int subtract(int x, int y){
        int answer = x-y;
        return answer;
    }

    public static int multiply(int x, int y){
        int answer = x*y;
        return answer;
    }

    public static int divide(int x, int y){
        int answer = x/y;
        return answer;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please don't post in CAPS, and try formatting your question so it's easier to read.

Comment: You should follow a [style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html) which will make your code more readable, and easier to debug.

Comment: @KevinHooke sorry about that, i'll be sure to lay off the caps next time,

Comment: @MatthewCliatt thank you, will look into it,

Answer (score 3):

You need to have the switch statement look like this:

```
switch (d)
{
    case 1: // look for the int 1 not the char '1'
        System.out.println("you choose addition!");

        // also, print out what the methods are returning:
        System.out.println("The answer is: " + add(a, b));
        break;
    case 2:
        subtract(a, b);
        break;
    case 3:
        multiply(a, b);
        break;
    case 4:
        divide(a, b);
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("You did not make a valid choice, please run the program again.");
        System.exit(0);
}
```

**Side Notes**:

- In your divide method you are doing integer division, which is not precise.
  You may want to consider doing the division with doubles and returning a double.

For example,

```
public static double divide (int x, int y)
{
    double answer = (double) x / (double) y;
    return answer;
}
```

- You should also [close](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#close()) out the Scanner before exiting the program.

Answer (score 0):

You are never setting an answer variable. Your add, sub, multiple, and divide methods return an int but you never assign it to answer.
Example:

```
int answer = 0;
answer=add(a, b);
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. You guys really helped me out. Didn't realize my switch case statement wasn't working for something that simple.